# Android MediaCodec dequeOutputBuffer always returns -1

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, deque, decoder, android-mediacodec

I am using the new `MediaCodec API` on `Jelly Bean` to decode an `h264 stream`.
Using the code snippets in the developer page , instantiated a decoder by name (taken from media_codec.xml), passed a surface and configured the codec.

The problem I am facing is, **dequeOutputBuffer always returns -1**.
Tried with a negative timeout to wait indefenitely, no luck with that.
Whenever I get a -1, refreshed the buffers using getOutputBuffers.

Please note that the same issue is seen when a custom app is used to parse the data from a media source and provide to decoder.

Any inputs on the above will be helpful

Comment: Can you please post your code. I would be happy to debug it further

Comment: Examples of mediacodec usage: http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/

Answer (score 1):

I had faced same problem. Incrementing `presentationTimeUs` parameter of `queueInputBuffer()`  on each call solved the issue.

For example,

`codec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, data.size, time, 0)
time += 66 //incrementing by 1 works too`

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is facing this problem (*as I did today*) while starting with **MediaCodec** make sure to release the output codecs after you're done with them:

```
mediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(index, render);
```

or else the codec will run out of available buffers pretty soon.

Answer (score 0):

It may be necessary to feed several input buffers before obtaining data in output buffer.

Answer (score 0):

-1 is `INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER`, meaning the output buffer queue is still being prepared and you just need to call `dequeueOutputBuffer` again.

Try using a work loop that calls `dequeueOutputBuffer` in a loop similar to [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer/MediaCodecTrackRenderer.java#L448):

> ```
>     while (drainOutputBuffer(positionUs, elapsedRealtimeUs)) {}
>     if (feedInputBuffer(true)) {
>       while (feedInputBuffer(false)) {}
>     }
> ```

where drainOutputBuffer is a method that calls `dequeueOutputBuffer`.